# Замена пробелов на перенос строки в файле средствами php

Tags: php, файлы

Есть txt файл в котором есть некий текст:

```
1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9
```

Нужно сделать так чтоб получилось:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если за исходный файл принять `file_1.txt`, а за файл с результатом `file_2.txt` и речь идет о замене одного пробела, то можно так:

```
file_put_contents('file_2.txt', '');
foreach (file('file_1.txt') as $row) {
    file_put_contents('file_2.txt', str_replace(' ', "\n", $row), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

И я поучаствую:

```
$withSpaces = file_get_contents('source.txt');
$noSpaces = str_replace(' ', PHP_EOL, $withSpaces);
file_put_contents('dest.txt', $noSpaces);
```

Короче?

```
file_put_contents('dest.txt', str_replace(' ', PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('source.txt')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Это совсем просто:

```
$handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");
$handle_w = fopen("output.txt", "w");
if ($handle) {
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $line = str_replace ( ' ' , "\n" , $line );
    fputs($handle_w, $line);
  }
  fclose($handle);
  fclose($handle_w);
} else {
  echo 'Ошибка чтения файла';
}
```

Comment: _'Ошибка чтения файла'_ - а ошибка записи идёт лесом?)